# Javascript innerHTML out of scope issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering why the following jsfiddle does not work.  And if there is anyway for it to work. Any ideas would be appreciated.  I would think since the html would include the variable name at the time, that it would work ... but it doesnt.  Weird.  I am using firefox, latest build.

What should happen: onclick should alert!

http://jsfiddle.net/VqA9g/125/

Comment: @Luka It does the alert?

Comment: @ClydeLobo Is it doing the alert for you?

Comment: @DorCohen Its doing the alert for you?

Comment: working fine here also..

Comment: The OP meant, he can't get the alerts to fire on clicking the text. The question is not clear, but I presume this is their problem by looking at the script, I've answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method call needs to quote the list_name.

Here's the edited script that works:

```
function example() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < list.length ; i++ ) {   
        var list_name = list[i];
        var div = document.getElementById('testing');
        div.innerHTML += "<txt onClick=\"test('" + list_name + "');\">" + list_name + "</txt><br>";
    }
}
```

With this little change, I can see the alerts working.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I think people are not reading the code and downvoting.  hehe.  Thanks for the help, I would have never even guessed that.  What does the "\" mean?

Comment: Your generated HTML, needs to be like <txt onClick="test('ZERO');">ZERO</txt><br>. it was test(ZERO) without quotes earlier. So ZERO without quotes is treated like an undefined variable.

Comment: \" is an escape sequence to escape ", otherwise your string gets terminated at the first instance of matching ". You may accept this answer, if it worked for you

Comment: Yes I will, thank you.  I get it now.  :-)  Learn something new everyday.

Comment: @Ohmages That's what makes stack overflow so addictive :)

Comment: The only issue i have with this answer is that every time in the loop a new variable is created :(

Comment: @ClydeLobo IMHO, that would not make any difference in javascript in modern browsers (Can't say that about IE6 and older). Can you quote some material which proves that declaring var in a loop in javascript hinders performance? I always thought otherwise, but this would be a wonderful revelation for me.

Comment: @AshwinPrabhu : You're right. I am stuck with the IE6 mindset, pretty hard to get out of it. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enclose the words in quotes. So with your code it was passing as a variable, that was not defined. Here is an updated version:

http://jsfiddle.net/VqA9g/131/